# How to replace "\" with "" or empty?

Tags: c#, string, replace

I want to use

```
XmlReader.Create(aString);
```

to read XML. but there are many "\" in this aString, which cause an error:

> Illegal characters in path.

So I want to replace all `"\"` with `""`.

I've tried:

```
aString.Replace("\", "");
aString.Replace("\\", "");
aString.Replace(@"\", "");
aString.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

None of them works.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you *sure* the backslashes are really there? If so, shouldn't you be going through some uniform unescaping first, rather than just backslashes? Also note that you're currently ignoring the return value of `Replace`, which isn't going to work. If you could give us more context, we may well be able to suggest a better option.

Comment: What goes wrong? Are you assigning the value of `aString.Replace("\\","");` back into aString?

Comment: How do you end up with a badly formed string in the first place? Maybe the better fix is upstream.

Comment: Both `@"\"` and `"\\"` should work.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You're marking as a duplicate of **closed as duplicate** question ;)

Comment: You have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752852/replacing-backslash-in-a-string

Comment: @abatishchev This question has been asked so many times, it's no wonder that sooner or later one would close a dupe pointing to another dupe :)

Comment: You can look at this for an alternative method of loading a XML file [Illegal characters in path error while parsing XML in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374729/illegal-characters-in-path-error-while-parsing-xml-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 7):

You're probably not capturing the output - `Replace` does not *modify* the existing string - it *returns* a new string.  Try:

```
aString = aString.Replace(@"\","");
```

Comment: This is immediately what I thought after looking at the OP

Comment: This is what I use in my code which doesn't work: string aString=model.wresult.ToString(); aString=aString.Replace(@"\",""); XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(aString);

Comment: What is your input string?  Are you sure the "\" character is the only illegal character?

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the output of `String.Replace()` method anywhere.
`Replace` method does not modify the object.

Comment: This is what I use in my code, which doesn't work: string aString=model.wresult.ToString(); aString=aString.Replace(@"\",""); XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(aString);

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are \" in your code. That is how VisualStudio shows ". (The \ is in the case a escape char and not the actual char. The data in aString is correct and there is no reason to try to remove the \ from aString. The problem lays with what you are doing with aString, and not with the \ inside aString.

Please note: `XmlReader.Create(aString);` reads a XML file from the path aString.
XmlDocument.LoadXml(string) parse a XML file.